# Add breakpoints to a source code file en masse

Tags: query-replace, ruby

I'm editing a `.rb` file with about 3000 lines of code.

This file has about 30+ statements that does a [.create(](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class)

`create()` appears in many ways:
as part of another expression: `puts Foo.create(...)`

or

multiline:

`Foo.create(
  baa: "baz"
)`

etc

We suspect there might be a bug close to the `create()`s, so we want to add a line containing the word "[byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)" to
the preceding line of any line containing `create(`

Can Emacs help me do this easily?

Comment: I would suggest `regex-builder` to help you build the regex that will match the string to replace. Then `replace-regexp` to do the replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we want to add a line containing the word "byebug" to the preceding line of any line containing `create(`

Here's a replace-regexp approach:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^.*create(` <kbd>RET</kbd> `byebug` <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> `\&` <kbd>RET</kbd>